# Relative XPath node selection with C# XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

Imagine the following XML document:

```
<root>
    <person_data>
        <person>
            <name>John</name>
            <age>35</age>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Jim</name>
            <age>50</age>
        </person>
    </person_data>
    <locations>
        <location>
            <name>John</name>
            <country>USA</country>
        </location>
        <location>
            <name>Jim</name>
            <country>Japan</country>
        </location>
    </locations>
</root>
```

I then select the person node for Jim:

```
XmlNode personNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//person[name = 'Jim']");
```

And now from this node with a single XPath select I would like to retrieve Jim's location node. Something like:

```
XmlNode locationNode = personNode.SelectSingleNode("//location[name = {reference to personNode}/name]");
```

Since I am selecting based on the personNode it would be handy if I could reference it in the select. Is this possible?.. is the connection there?

Sure I could put in a few extra lines of code and put the name into a variable and use this in the XPath string but that is not what I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not very efficient, but it should work. The larger the file gets, the slower will this be.

```
string xpath = "//location[name = //person[name='Jim']/name]";
XmlNode locationNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

Here is why this is inefficient:

- The "`//`" shorthand causes a document-wide scan of all nodes.
- The "`[]`" predicate runs in a loop, once for each `<person>` matched by "`//person`".
- The second "`//`" causes a causes a document-wide scan again, this time once for each `<person>`.

This means you get quadratic O(n²) worst-case performance, which is bad. If there are n `<person>`s and n `<location>`s in your document, n x n document wide scans happen. All out of one innocent looking XPath expression.

I'd recommend against that approach. A two-step selection (first, find the person, then the location) will perform better.

Comment: I am not trying to avoid the two steps. A personNode is always selected first. So the question is if I from a given personNode can find that persons location?.. but with a single XPath in a personNode.SelectSingleNode call.

Comment: There is no way to use a .NET object as a reference of some sort in an XPath expression, if that is what you ask. XPath is string based and has no notion of taking any node references from "outside". You can only build a new XPath string, like this: string xpath = "//location[name = '" + personNode.Attributes["name"].Value + "'"]; -- but this will fail if the @name value contains single quotes and/or double quotes.

Comment: Ok, so to answer the question as it goes "the connection is not there". I was hoping it was.. since the SelectSingleNode is called on the personNode object so I was looking for some sort of connection. But i guess there is none.

Comment: No, there is none. XPath is detached from the context your program is in. Every query can yield a node list, but every query stands on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting the `location` node based on the `person` node, rather you are selecting it based on the *value* of the node. The value is just a string and in this case, it can be used to formulate a predicate condition that selects the `location` node based on the value within ("Jim").

Comment: I am not sure I get that... so it can be done with the single XPath expression? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure why you want refer location from `personNode`. Since, the name already exists in `location` node you can very well use the same to get the location node corresponding to 'Jim'.

```
XPath would be: //location[name = 'Jim']
```

Comment: +1 Was was about to ask the same thing. My guess is that the contrived example does not at all reflect the real problem. I think unless the OP reveals the real XML, this is the most sensible and obvious solution.

Comment: The xml structure is merely a simplified example of the real world structure so don't worry about that, it is just to illustrate the problem. The question is if the second xpath expression can somehow access the values of the personNode.

Comment: But you already know the *name* value of the personNode, since that's how you selected it!

Comment: Sure, but let's pretend somebody else hands me the personNode... input param in a method  or something. And yes I could just manually extract the name but as the question goes... can it be done in the single select with a single xpath? Nevermind what else I could and should do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNode locationNode = personNode.SelectSingleNode("..");
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that your real XML document is more complex than your example, but one thing does strike me about it. It resembles a relational data store containing the following:

- A `person` table with two columns - `name` and `age`.
- A `location` table with two columns - `name` and `country`.
- A 1-1 relationship between the two tables joining on the two `name` columns.

With that in mind, the XPath becomes obvious. You just select on the primary key value of the table whose data you want.

```
//location[name = 'Jim']
```

I know that aJ already proposed that solution, and it was rejected, but if you generalise the idea to the real XML schema, you get this:

```
//real_2nd_table_name[real_2nd_pk_column_name_1 = real_1st_pk_column_value_1 and real_2nd_pk_column_name_2 = real_1st_pk_column_value_2 and real_2nd_pk_column_name_3 = real_1st_pk_column_value_3 ...]
```

In other words:

1. You already know the PK values used to find the row in the first table.
2. You know how the two tables are related.
3. Therefore you should be able to work out how to express a PK query on the second table using the same values that you would have used to select the row in the first table.