# how to retrieve and display XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, httprequest

Well the problem is that I am new to `asp.net` technology and I am stuck on a problem.

Now the scenario is that I have to send an `HTTPrequest` to another server from my page, lets say `myGames.aspx` and in response to the request the server sends me an `XML` file. Now I don't know how to handle this situation, I mean I am like a total noob :(

Also I don't have just to display the data, I have to send different fields of the `XML` to different databse tables, but thats a later issue, I'd first like to do some practice with the `XML` data just on screen before involving in sending it to database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To play with the XML data if you are using .net version 3.5 its better to user [**LINQ to XML**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML

**or**

[Manipulate XML data with XPath and XmlDocument (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C)

Comment: yeah I m using .NET version 4, thanks I will take a look at it

Comment: but the problem is that I don't know how to capture or catch the XML file after sending an WebRequest :(

Answer (score 1):

if you are get response Xml as URL Format than u can load like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102865/asp-net-load-xml-file-from-url)

and get xml element nodes element or you can also filter linq query using below link

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/access-xml-data-using-linq-to-xml/594

Hops some helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's several options:

You could query the data using [Linq To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class. This is recommended if using .NET 3.5 or above.

You could load the data into an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class using the [LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) method and use [XPath to SelectSingleNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/956169/4950) for display.

You could use an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) and read the document by [looping over the nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441694/4950)